# What does the option 'Complexexpand' do in the Collect command?

Tags: syntax

I'm trying to re-write a long chain of commands I've received in pdf from Mathematica language to Maxima. I have this command:

```
Collect[%, ε, ComplexExpand]
```

I know what the `Collect` command does. But what does the `ComplexExpand` option do here? Will it perform

```
Collect(ComplexExpand(%),ε)
```

or

```
ComplexExpand(Collect(%),ε)
```

or something else? I did not see the `ComplexExpand` option for `Collect` in the documentation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the third syntax form in the documentation of Collect: "Collect[expr, var, h]
applies $h$ to the expression that forms the coefficient of each term obtained". Look at the results of `Collect[a x + b y, x, f]` to study how it operates.

Comment: Hi @MarcoB I don't have Mathematica installed.

Comment: I see. That command will run `ComplexExpand` on each one of the expressions that have been identified as coefficients of the variable. So for instance, the result of the example I gave would be `x f[a] + f[b y]`.